# How to re-pack odin recovery image?

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, odin

I want to change the recovery image from ODIN package for Samsung P601. I've unpacked the archive and got recovery.img.
Next I've tried to do `simg2img recovery.img recovery.raw.img`, but it says:

> Invalid sparse file format at header magi Failed to read sparse file

I think that means that it should not be converted.
I've tried to mount it, but the FS seems to be not ext4.

So, the question is - how to mount recovery.img, change files there and save it back? I'm using OS X and Windows (with cygwin).

Comment: This may help http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/general/ref-unpacking-repacking-stock-rom-img-t1081239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unmkbootimg` from [this thread on XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1877807).

```
$ unmkbootimg recovery.img
```

This should give you two files: `initramfs.cpio.gz` and `zImage` (the kernel image). To extract `initramfs.cpio.gz` use this command:

```
$ mkdir ramdisk && cd ramdisk
$ gunzip -c ../initramfs.cpio.gz | cpio -i
```

Check [this post](http://www.imajeenyus.com/computer/20130301_android_tablet/android/unpack_repack_recovery_image.html) for more detailed information.

EDIT:
I just realized I only answered half of the question. To re-pack the image after making changes to the extracted files, use the command that `unmkbookimg` gave you, e.g.

```
mkbootimg --kernel zImage --ramdisk initramfs.cpio.gz --base 0x40000000 --cmdline 'console=ttyS0,115200 rw init=/init loglevel=8' -o new_boot.img
```

According to the article, use this command to create the new initramfs.cpio.gz file (untested):

```
find . | cpio -o -H newc | gzip > ../newramdisk.cpio.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Recovery isn't a sparse image (which is an Ext4) so you cannot do that, neither mount it. It's a boot image for which you can use mkbootimg.